# sqlite3 and rails server with load error

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, sqlite

I am using ROR in windows, I downloaded RailsInstaller and everything works fine until I call 
  rails server

The page is loaded with error "cannot load such file -- sqlite3"

I guess I am missing sqlite3 dll but if I download one, where should I leave it in the currently installed Rails folder ? Thank you so much.

[**Update**]
Thank you for reading and for your concern
I have fixed it all the ways as you told me but I still have the same problem with LoadError "can not load such file -- sqlite3". I don't know what to do now.

Answer (score 2):

`sqlite3-ruby` (and `sqlite3`) gems are installed by default with RailsInstaller, you can verify that doing `gem list sqlite3` from a Command Prompt

Starting from sqlite3 1.3.4 the binary gem on Windows do not depend on external `sqlite3.dll` so there is no need of additional download and copy of anything.

Now, the error you're getting might be associated with missing that gem in your `Gemfile`, which most likely require you add:

```
gem "sqlite3", "~> 1.3.6"
```

To the mentioned `Gemfile` and then perform `bundle install` in the root of your application directory.

You can also check if sqlite3 gem is installed proper from a Interactive Ruby console (IRB):

```
require "rubygems"
require "sqlite3"
puts SQLite3::VERSION
```

Answer (score 0):

You won't put it in your rails directory. You'll put it in `/WINDOWS/system32` or somewhere else that's in your PATH environment variable.

Answer (score -1):

Download the pre-compiled version of SQLite3 >=3.5.4 from the SQLite web site, unzip it and copy the single sqlite3.exe to my ruby/bin directory.

Now that SQLite3 is installed, just install the gem:

```
gem install sqlite3-ruby
```

Hope that helps.

Answer (score -1):

Have you installed sqlite? If not, I suggest you do the following:

- Download "sqlite-shell-win32-x86-3071201.zip" from http://www.sqllite.org
- Unzip and copy `sqlite3.exe` to `c:/ruby193/bin`. (`c:/ruby193` is where I've installed ruby)
- Run the command `c:\gem install sqlite3`.

Comment: this doesn't solve the problem for me..any other way you made this to work?